# Extract names of dataframe in list of dataframes and add it to columnnames

Tags: r, list, multiple-columns, rename, paste

I have a list of dataframes:

```
set.seed(23) 
date_list = seq(1:30)
testframe = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe$ABC = rnorm(30)
testframe$DEF = rnorm(30)
testframe$GHI = seq(from = 10, to = 25, length.out = 30)
testframe$JKL = seq(from = 5, to = 45, length.out = 30)

testlist = list(testframe, testframe, testframe)
names(testlist) = c("df1464", "df6355", "df94566")
```

I want now to extract the name of each dataframe and add it to its columns. So the columnnames of the first dataframe in the list should be: `Date_df1464, ABC_df1464, DEF_df1464, GHI_df1464 and JKL_df1464`

I created this loop, but its not working:

```
for (a  in names(testlist)) {
  for(i in 1: length(testlist)){
    allcolnames = colnames(testlist[[i]])
    allcolnames = paste(allcolnames, a , sep = "_")
    testlist[[i]] = colnames(allcolnames)
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in testlist[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am pretty clueless why it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was nearly right, you just do not need to loop two times.
And your `colnames` call was the wrong way around.
This should work:

```r
for(i in 1: length(testlist)){
    allcolnames = colnames(testlist[[i]])
    allcolnames = paste(allcolnames, names(testlist)[i] , sep = "_")
    colnames(testlist[[i]]) = allcolnames
}
```

This also works, without any fors ;):

```r
set.seed(23) 
date_list = seq(1:30)
testframe = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe$ABC = rnorm(30)
testframe$DEF = rnorm(30)
testframe$GHI = seq(from = 10, to = 25, length.out = 30)
testframe$JKL = seq(from = 5, to = 45, length.out = 30)

testlist = list(testframe, testframe, testframe)
names(testlist) = c("df1464", "df6355", "df94566")

out <- lapply(names(testlist),function(name){
  dummy <- testlist[[name]]
  names(dummy) <- paste0(names(testlist[[name]]) ,'_',name)
  dummy
})
str(out)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Date_df1464: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ ABC_df1464 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
#>   ..$ DEF_df1464 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
#>   ..$ GHI_df1464 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
#>   ..$ JKL_df1464 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Date_df6355: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ ABC_df6355 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
#>   ..$ DEF_df6355 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
#>   ..$ GHI_df6355 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
#>   ..$ JKL_df6355 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Date_df94566: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ ABC_df94566 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
#>   ..$ DEF_df94566 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
#>   ..$ GHI_df94566 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
#>   ..$ JKL_df94566 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to practise loops, that is why i choose to do it like this. Your suggestion doesnt work since the a is not in a loop...but it helped me to find my own mistake!

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to accomplish this. The better, more encapsulated way would be to use `Map`, looping over the individual data frames and their corresponding names:

```
new.testlist <- Map(function(df, name) {
  names(df) <- paste(names(df), name, sep = '_')
  return(df)
}, testlist, names(testlist))

> str(new.testlist)
List of 3
 $ df1464 :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Date_df1464: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ ABC_df1464 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
  ..$ DEF_df1464 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
  ..$ GHI_df1464 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
  ..$ JKL_df1464 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
 $ df6355 :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Date_df6355: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ ABC_df6355 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
  ..$ DEF_df6355 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
  ..$ GHI_df6355 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
  ..$ JKL_df6355 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
 $ df94566:'data.frame':    30 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Date_df94566: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ ABC_df94566 : num [1:30] 0.193 -0.435 0.913 1.793 0.997 ...
  ..$ DEF_df94566 : num [1:30] -0.5532 0.0982 -1.1467 -1.2499 -0.2021 ...
  ..$ GHI_df94566 : num [1:30] 10 10.5 11 11.6 12.1 ...
  ..$ JKL_df94566 : num [1:30] 5 6.38 7.76 9.14 10.52 ...
```

The riskier way would be to use the super assignment operator to loop over the names, trusting that `testlist` remains reliable in your global environment. Note that this second method changes the column names in `testlist` as a side effect, and is generally NOT considered good practice. Max Teflon's answer is somewhat similar, in that it relies on `testlist` existing in the global environment, without passing it explicitly to the modifying function.

```
sapply(names(testlist), function(x) {
  names(testlist[[x]]) <<- paste(names(testlist[[x]]), x, sep = '_')
})
```

Comment: Thank you! The 2nd solution is also great. Looks easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could switch two `Map` in series; the inner `Map` prepares the new names, the outer `Map` applies it onto the sublists' names.

```
testlist <- Map(`names<-`, testlist,
                Map(paste, lapply(testlist, names), names(testlist), sep="_"))
```

***Result***

```
lapply(testlist, names)
# $df1464
# [1] "Date_df1464" "ABC_df1464"  "DEF_df1464"  "GHI_df1464"  "JKL_df1464" 
# 
# $df6355
# [1] "Date_df6355" "ABC_df6355"  "DEF_df6355"  "GHI_df6355"  "JKL_df6355" 
# 
# $df94566
# [1] "Date_df94566" "ABC_df94566"  "DEF_df94566"  "GHI_df94566"  "JKL_df94566"
```

Comment: Thank you! That is working great, but I want to practise loops, so I searched for a loop solution. But thx for the alternative way!